# Polymorphism. Problems with copy arrays

Tags: java

```
Empleado[] empleados = new Empleado[3];
empleados[0] = new Empleado("Alfredo", 20000, 2020, 6, 01);
empleados[1] = new Empleado("Alejandro", 21000, 2020, 7, 04);
empleados[2] = new Jefatura("Laura", 25000, 2010, 3, 6);
Jefatura jefeRRHH = (Jefatura) empleados[3]; // CASTEO
jefeRRHH.setIncentivo(1000);
```

Why is it that when i set the incentive for jefeRRHH, empleados[2] is changed? I thought if jefeRRHH was modified this didn't affect the array empleados.

I mean, when I walk the vector with a foreach loop, empleados[2] give me back with the incentive applied.

```
package poo;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        String Nombre = "José";
        int j = 1;
        
        String[] nombres = new String[1];
        nombres[0] = Nombre;
        
        int a = j;
        
        Nombre= "Maria";
        
        System.out.println(Nombre);
        System.out.println(nombres[0]);
        
        j=2;
        
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

Why isn't the same thing here?

When I declare the new variables I'm not assigning addresses, I'm assigning copies, right?

Comment: This should throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: You are simply copying *references* around, the objects are not copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hold true for all Objects in Java.

Assuming a simple class:

```java
public class Foo {

}
```

When you then instantiate an object of class `Foo`, you will actually allocate memory on heap, construct a Foo-Object and retrieve the adress to this location, which will then be stored in the object variable:

```java
Foo f = new Foo(); // f points to a Foo-Object
```

So, instead of copying the actual object, the reference will be copied...

```java
Foo farr[] = new Foo[1]; // create array with a capacity of 1
Foo f = new Foo(); // f now holds the adress to an actual Foo-Object
farr[0] = f; // farr[0] now holds the adress to the SAME Foo-Object
```

Here is a nice [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-object-and-reference-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20objects%20are%20created%20in,object%20(in%20the%20heap).&text=In%20short%2C%20object%20is%20an,created%20in%20the%20heap%20area.) about references and objects,
and here is a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/9233560) as follow-up-reading

---

Furthermore there are primitive datatypes and String-literals.

Primitive datatypes are always simply copied, whatever happens. So there will never be the case, where you change one primitive variable and another one changes.

Strings on the other hand are a bit trickier. They are objects wrapped around a `char[]`, and therefore are (as already stated by others here) immutable and share a so called String constant pool. Modifying a String will therefore result in a new String with the result, and the original String remains unmodified.

Comment: I've answered myself with another example where I don't see the same behavior. I understand your answer, but I can't understand it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in the code, you should reference the element with index 2 here:

```java
Jefatura jefeRRHH = (Jefatura) empleados[3]; // CASTEO
```

So, you create a new object with

```java
new Jefatura("Laura", 25000, 2010, 3, 6);
```

and store a reference to it in the element of the empleados array with index 2. Then you say that jefeRRHH will be another reference to the same object. Now you have two references pointing at the same object. Think about them like different names (or nicknames if you like) of the same person. When you access/modify the object using any of the references you change the same object, so the changes are visible through any other names/references.

Comment: Does this always happen with objects? Do we always store a pointer to the memory address?

So, if I urge the String class, will I also have a pointer to the memory address where the name is stored?

Comment: Yes, this is always happening with object, "the variable" is just a reference, that is it keeps "an address" where in the memory the object data are located. The example with String is a bit more complicated, because strings are immutable objects. So, when you do `String s = "abc";` variable `s` will keep address of literal "abc" in the memory. When you do after that `s += "def"` the variable `s` will keep a **different** address, pointing to literal "abcdef" somewhere in the memory. It's because String is immutable and the new literal "abcdef" is not placed in the same memory where "abc" was.

Comment: This then only happens with objects from created classes. When I urge the class to store a pointer to the object in memory, right? Does it happen in any other case? Does it happen to objects instantiated from the default classes as well?